# Is there an equation for sine?

Tags: trigonometry

When I was younger I was already interested in math. I wrote a lot of equations for fun. A year ago I remembered that I once wrote an equation that would calculate the height of a certain object given the height of your eyes, the distance to the object and the angle you are seeing it's top at. At that time I was quite young and so I also didn't know about trigonometric functions which means that I must've written an equation for sine. That's why I wonder: is my memory bad, was my equation wrong or is there really an equation for sine. I was searching for it on the internet but all I could find were approximations and repetetive equations. I also sat down and tried to redo it on the paper but I couldn't...

Comment: I don't think there's any formula you would have written down. There's an infinite series for sine, but that probably wasn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "equation". You can not express $\sin(x)$ with whole number and $+,-,\times, /,\sqrt{}$ and such. But you can can

1) Do an infinite series:
$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} \pm ...$

2) use complex numbers: $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$

3) express it using other trigonometric functions: $sin(x) = \pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$